# Did the Romulans make any major concessions in the Treaty of Algeron?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, romulan

In TNG's *the Pegasus*, it was revealed the Federation agreed not to equip spacecraft with cloaking devices in the Treaty of Algeron, an in-universe reason the writers came up with to explain why Starfleet ships don't have cloaks.

Someone commented on this on the site *Jammer's Reviews*, saying that the Federation should never have agreed to this; but another commenter pointed out the episode never mentioned what the Romulans might have given up in the treaty- does anyone know what compromises (if any) the Romulans might have made?

Comment: ["*The treaty reinforced and redefined the Romulan Neutral Zone, and made clear that any violations of the Zone without adequate notification, by either side, would be considered an act of war.*"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Treaty_of_Algeron) - So, the Federation got peace and tranquillity and the Romulans agreed not to invade and in return, the Federation wouldn't develop a cloak.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  Per the Enterprise Incident...COMMANDER: You realise that very soon we will learn to penetrate the cloaking device you stole.
SPOCK: Obviously. Military secrets are the most fleeting of all. I hope that you and I exchanged something more permanent.